# similar between or similar for?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, among-between

For a research project I have a question about the correctness of the following phrases

The mean activities were similar *between* group A and group B.
The study demonstrated similarity in terms of antimicrobial activity *between* product A and product B.

Is the word "between" correct here, or would "for" or "of" be more appropriate. Thank you for you advice

Answer (score 2):

Use 'in' instead of 'between' here.

"The mean activities were similar **in** group A and group B. The study demonstrated similarity in terms of antimicrobial activity **in** product A and product B"

Comment: I get where you're coming from, but it would be helpful to explain to the OP **why** it should be "in".